# Select tag losing children onChange in Knockout Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a template in a knockout-kendo grid to create a `<select>` tag. Unfortunately, every time the `<select>` value is changed, *every* `<select>` on the grid loses it's values that I have bound to them. This also happens when I try to apply a kendoDatePicker to an input field. It's as if the innerHTML is being lost when something changes.

[Screenshot of the issue, starts like the left, and changes to the right after changing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcVqt.png)

```
    {
        title: 'Something',
        template: '<select id="cboSomething_#=ID#"' +
            'onChange="cp.ItemCollection().BindChanges(' +
            '#= kendo.toString(ID) #' +
            ',6)">' +
            '</select>'
    },
```

ItemCollection is the collection of items (a ko.observableArray()). cp is an object holding an ItemsCollection() as a ko.observable() created on the page. BindChanges is a workaround for the two way binding not working right for templates, and looks like this on the collection:

```
self.BindChanges = function (classID, field) {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(cp.ItemsCollection().items(), function (item) {
        if (item.ID() == classID) {
            item.BindChange(field);
        };
    });
}
```

And feeds into this function on each individual item:

```
self.BindChange = function (field, value) {
    switch (field) {
        ...
        case 6:
            self.SomethingID($("#cboSomething_" + self.ID()).val());
            self.IsDirty(true);
            $("#btnCPSave").addClass("highlightButton");
            cp.ItemsCollection().BindSomethingCombos();
            break;
    }
}
```

BindSomethingCombos is my attempt to fix the problem for each `<select>` in the grid.

```
    self.BindSomethingCombos = function () {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(cp.ItemCollection().items(), function (item) {
            item.BindSomethingComboBox();
        });
    }
```

And feeds into this on the item level:

```
self.BindSomethingComboBox = function () {
    $('#cboSomething_' + self.ID())
            .html(cp.ItemsCollection().SomethingOptions());
    $('#cboSomething_' + self.ID())
            .val(self.SomethingID());
}
```

SomethingOptions is just a generated string observable which contains `<option>` tags. The `<options>` are well formed, but the `<select>` keeps losing them! Sorry for the long-winded post, but I'm stumped. I've tried binding the comboboxes over again at each step, to no avail.

EDIT: For clarity, I'm trying to create a column that contains a `<select>` tag for each row.

Comment: Since you're using kendo grid, why not use kendo's combobox or dropdownlist? There's also a kendo-knockout plugin that has some features you may find helpful to your situation.

Comment: I am using knockout-kendo, but knockout-kendo only binds to the top-level of the view-model. If there's a way to data-bind in the column template that is simple, I don't know of it.

Comment: The primary use of the kendo-knockout library for this would have you set up your element as <input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { ...options... }" /> I've had much better experiences with using these and providing context-specific parameters in my options. It seems like your problem is really your context and that all your 'select' elements are given the same bindings...hence the group refresh. Try using the kendo extensions and see where that takes you.

Comment: I don't know how I'd do that inside the column though. ApplyBindings would generate the grid, which __then__ generates the template in the column. I could just be wrong, though. I'm not sure how I could apply a new set of KO bindings inside an already bound grid like that...

Comment: Have you looked at the editing template here :: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. The problem was that when I clicked my **Save Changes** button, I was putting the `BindSomethingCombos()` method outside of the $.post. Once I put it inside, it runs *after* the async call and rebinds the combos successfully. The boxes still flash blank momentarily, but it works...

Non-working code:

```
$.post(urlSaveItem,
        {
            ...
        }
        , function (data) {
            if (data.ID != undefined || data.ID != 0) {
                self.IsDirty(false);
                ...
            }
            else {
                self.IsDirty(true);
                ...
            }
            cp.ItemCollection().BindSomethingCombos();
        });
```

Working code:

```
    $.post(urlSaveItem,
        {
            ...
        }
        , function (data) {
            if (data.ID != undefined || data.ID != 0) {
                self.IsDirty(false);
                ...
                cp.ItemCollection().BindSomethingCombos();
            }
            else {
                self.IsDirty(true);
                ...
                cp.ItemCollection().BindSomethingCombos();
            }
        });
```

*I would like to point out that this is NOT best practices code, and although I had to make it work for my particular situation, you should use Kendo's editor templates instead if you can.*